# Spring Boot multiple files upload with multiple objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, postman

I need help I last time create the controller with the single file upload with an object and it's work for me like

My POJO class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "file", "data" })
public class FileWithObject<T> {

    @JsonProperty("file")
    private MultipartFile file;
    @JsonRawValue
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private T data;
}
```

> MY REST CONTOLLER

```
@RequestMapping(value="/filestore/{bucket-uuid}/appsport.com/singleFileUploadWithObject/{folder}",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
// api work
public String singleFileUploadWithObject(
        @PathVariable(name="bucket-uuid", required = true) String bucketUUId,
        @PathVariable(name="folder", required = false) String folder,
        FileWithObject rawData) {
    return pingResponse;
}
```

My Postman result

[image]

That's all work for me. How to send the list of the objects through the postman or is possible to handle that way request like below rest controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/filestore/{bucket-uuid}/appsport.com/listOfObjectsWithSingleFile/{folder}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String listOfObjectsWithSingleFile(
        @PathVariable(name="bucket-uuid", required = true) String bucketUUId,
        @PathVariable(name="folder", required = false) String folder,
        Set<FileWithObject> rawData) {
    return pingResponse;
}
```

How to handle list of objects

```
[{
"file": fileobject,
"data": "zyz"
},{
"file": fileobject,
"data": "zyz"
}]
```

> I'm trying to creating the api for this blow task

[image]

Comment: In the controller annotate `rawData` method parameter with `@RequestParam` and in Postman name the file parameteres `rawData.file`. As a generic hint the request parameters names should match the object structure of the server side objects which will receive the values

Comment: my question is how to tackle the request of the list objects under the request param. single file upload I know the way.

Comment: if sending one file is working, then you need to add a property of type `List<MultipartFile>` in the `FileWithObject`. Something similar with `@JsonProperty("file") private MultipartFile file;` but the type should be a collection and the name of `@JsonProperty` should be something different then `file`

Comment: Look at this example:https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this by use of **Meta-Data** concept there are few changes I did in **controller and bean**

> Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/filestore/{bucket-uuid}/appsport.com/listOfObjectsWithSingleFile/{folder}",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String listOfObjectsWithSingleFile(
        @PathVariable(name="bucket-uuid") String bucketUUId, @PathVariable(name="folder") String folder,
        FileWithObject objects) { // change this Set<FileWithObject> rawData to FileWithObject objects
    return pingResponse;
}
```

> Bean

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "file", "files", "data" })
public class FileWithObject<T> {

    @JsonProperty("file")
    private MultipartFile file;
    @JsonProperty("files")
    private List<MultipartFile> files;
    @JsonRawValue
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private T data;

    // work like (meta-data)
    List<FileWithObject> rawData;
    // getter setter
}
```

> Image's For Request

[image]
[image]

> Note:- I'm Still looking for this issue handle this in a blow way

```
@RequestMapping(value="/filestore/{bucketuuid}/appsport.com/listOfObjectsWithSingleFile/{folder}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String listOfObjectsWithSingleFile(@PathVariable(name="bucket-uuid", required = true) String bucketUUId,
    @PathVariable(name="folder", required = false) String folder,Set<FileWithObject> rawData) {
    return pingResponse;
}
```

hope it helps some one

Comment: full code of all possible file upload with spring https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/file-uploader