# How can I add multiple files with 2 fields in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, multipartfile

```
My request DTO :
@Getter
@Setter
public class FileUploadRequestDTO {
    private MultipartFile fileMap;
    private String filetype;
    private String fileNature;
}


// Controller method
@RequestMapping(path = FLAT_FILE_UPLOAD, method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponseDTO> flatFileUpload(List<FileUploadRequestDTO> fileDTO){

}
```

**
Question:

I want to send multiple files with the following variables in the request body. How to achieve this in Postman?

**

Comment: look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929236/4631177

Comment: Thank you @Alireza. This link helped :)